Assign each list element to a row of pandas dataframe sequentially and equally
I have a pandas dataframe with 25 rows, and also a list with 5 elements. How do I:
- assign 1st element of the list to first row of the dataframe
- 2nd element of the list to second row
- ...
- 1st element to 6th row of dataframe etc

Eg: Need to assign a doctor to each patient sequentially
df:
| Name | Gender |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | Male            |
| Second   | Female           |
| Third    | Male             |
| Fourth   | Male             |
| Fifth    | Male             |  

list_doctor = ['andrea','anup']
Required Output:
| Name     | Gender         |  Doctor |
| -------- | -------------- |---------|
| First    | Male           |andrea   |
| Second   | Female         |anup     |
| Third    | Male           |andrea   |
| Fourth   | Male           |anup     |
| Fifth    | Male           |andrea   |

Tried with iterrows, but all rows are being assigned to the same name
for index, row in df.iterrows():
for doctor in l_doctor:
    print(index, doctor)
    df.loc[index,'Assignee'] = doctor


Approach
To avoid Python for loop we can use itertools functions cycle and islice as follows:

cycle to make an iterator that will indefinitely loop through a list
islice to create an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable
list to instantiate the iterator elements

Code
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle, islice

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male']
})

docs = ['andrea', 'anup']

df['Doctor'] = list(islice(cycle(docs), 0, len(df)))

print(df)

Output
    Name  Gender  Doctor
0   First    Male  andrea
1  Second  Female    anup
2   Third    Male  andrea
3  Fourth    Male    anup
4   Fifth    Male  andrea


Surprised nobody brought of np.resize.
Try:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male']
})

docs = ['andrea', 'anup']
df['Doctor'] = np.resize(docs, len(df))

print(df)

np.resize is the easiest and cleanest way here IMHO.

Code
The solution in Pandas is as follows:
docs = ['andrea', 'anup']
df['Doctor'] = (df.index % len(docs)).map(dict(enumerate(docs)))

df:
    Name    Gender  Doctor
0   First   Male    andrea
1   Second  Female  anup
2   Third   Male    andrea
3   Fourth  Male    anup
4   Fifth   Male    andrea


You can just create the doctor list directly:
df['Doctor'] = [list_doctor[i % len(list_doctor)] for i in range(len(df))]

df
     Name  Gender  Doctor
0   First    Male  andrea
1  Second  Female    anup
2   Third    Male  andrea
3  Fourth    Male    anup
4   Fifth    Male  andrea


You can use a list comprehension with bitwise i & (len(docs) - 1) or docs[i & len(docs)]:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male']
})

docs = ['andrea', 'anup']
l = len(docs)
df['Doctor'] = [docs[i & (l - 1)] for i in range(len(df))]
# df['Doctor'] = [docs[i % l)] for i in range(len(df))]

print(df)


Prints
     Name  Gender  Doctor
0   First    Male  andrea
1  Second  Female    anup
2   Third    Male  andrea
3  Fourth    Male    anup
4   Fifth    Male  andrea

